# MySql - Update a field of each row with a value of another field of another row

Tags: mysql

I have a table `joomla_jdownloads_cats_backup` with a lot of fields. The important fields are: `cat_dir_parent`, `parent_id`, `cat_dir_name`, `cat_id`

The values of `cat_dir_parent`, `cat_dir_name`, `cat_id` are correct. `cat_dir_name` is the name of a directory, `cat_dir_parent` is the root path of `cat_dir_name`, `cat_id` is a database id for that directory. Example:

```
cat_dir_parent  cat_dir_name    cat_id  parent_id
MyRootDir       dir1            1       ?
MyRootDir       dir2            2       ?
                MyRootDir       3       ?
```

The values of `parent_id` should be inserted with a **MySql UPDATE**, but I didn't find any way to it after hours of trials...

For each row, the `parent_id` should be equal to the `cat_id` of the `cat_dir` which is equal to the `cat_dir_parent` of the given row, or `0` is there isn't any parent. For example:

```
cat_dir_parent  cat_dir_name    cat_id  parent_id
MyRootDir       dir1            1       3
MyRootDir       dir2            2       3
                MyRootDir       3       0
```

What MySql code can perform this task?

I need to do the following steps, I don't know how to do them:

- for each row, I read the `cat_dir_parent`
- I select the `cat_id` whose `cat_dir_name` is equal to the given `cat_dir_parent`
- I set `parent_id` equal to the selected `cat_id`

This was my last trial, without success:

```
UPDATE joomla_jdownloads_cats_backup t1
INNER JOIN
joomla_jdownloads_cats_backup t2
ON t1.cat_dir_parent = t2.cat_dir_name
SET t1.parent_id = t2.cat_id
```

Comment: Is the error message or unexpected behaviour you experienced classified for some reasòn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to `UPDATE` the `parent_id` successfully using the query similar to yours. I just used `LEFT JOIN` to set the `parent_id` to `0` of the rows with out parent, just in case its initial value is `NULL`. Otherwise if you prefer on using `INNER JOIN`, you have to set the `parent_id` of the said records manually to `0` base from your requirement, and this will also work.

```
UPDATE joomla_jdownloads_cats_backup T1
  LEFT JOIN joomla_jdownloads_cats_backup T2 ON T1.cat_dir_parent = T2.cat_dir_name
  SET T1.parent_id = IFNULL(T2.cat_id, 0);
```

[LEFT JOIN SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36e20/1)

[INNER JOIN SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4895ce/1)